# How to use dopbox api to upload folders with flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I want to upload folders in dropbox using flutter app but i dont know how to acces dropbox api in flutter, i need to know how to start

I know how to upload in firebase or other databases but not with an api

Answer (score 0):

used `file_picker` plugin.. you can simply upload single or multiple files to dropbox. not only dropbox and google drive and iCloud

[file_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker)